# Using ServiceMix to Proxy Remote Web Service

Tags: apache-camel, cxf, esb, apache-servicemix

This might be obvious but i just still don't understand how i'd do it with ServiceMix :
An external web service http://mypartner.com/service/partnerService
My platform is for example http://myservicemix.com/
I'd like to use OSGI bundles

Is this what i need ? :

- A cxfbc:provider (this is the one that talks to the remote service, just a wsdl in the bundle right ?)
- A camel route and transformations to bridge the two
- A jaxrs:server (i'd like to expose it as a REST service)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cxfbc is a JBI component. JBI is essentially dead/legacy, so I suggest to not use that for new projects. You can read more about JBI is dead here: http://gnodet.blogspot.com/2010/12/thoughts-about-servicemix.html

So Apache ServiceMix is the server where you can host your Camel applications. So I suggest to look into how to do a webservice proxy with Camel.

For example there is an example with Camel
http://camel.apache.org/cxf-proxy-example.html

That example is OSGi ready and can be deployed in Apache ServiceMix.

Also check out some of the CXF examples that are shipped with Apache ServiceMix, in the examples directory

The Camel CXF component can do both REST and WS.
Also there is the camel-restlet component for REST support as well: http://camel.apache.org/restlet

Comment: Thank you so much Claus ! I was aware that JBI was almost dead but did not know that the cxfbc was jbi (there is a whole lot i don't know!?) There is just so much in servicemix that a newbie like me is easily lost. I'll check the links you suggest. Thanks again

Comment: The BC of the cxfbc name is JBI specific: Binding Component. And there is also a term SE = Service Engine

Comment: By reading the docs i can see how routing works but i don't understand how to "implement" the endpoints : the exposed rsServer ( what logic would it contain since it is just a proxy ) and the rsClient (do i just code a normal  client) that speaks to the remote service.

In fact, what i still don't understand is the server's and client's inner interface to camel (if we can call it so)

Comment: This article http://benoday.blogspot.com/2010/12/basic-rest-service-in-apache-cxf-vs.html helped me understand a bit more, especially the comment that says "strangely, this method is not called, only serves to configure the endpoint" on the cxf-camel example...